# How to execute getter setter methods, from a test class

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

This is my sample class

```
public class className{

    public className()
    {
       loadData();
    }
        public Boolean showNTC 
        {
            get
            {
                if(reg[0].Status__c == 'In Review')
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else return false;
            }private set;
        }
        public void loadData()
        {
         loadingSomedata=...
        }
    }
```

I've used following code to execute and return the boolean value : in VF page

```
<apex:commandButton rendered="{!showNTC}" value="Refresh" styleClass="btn styled-button1"}">
```

Everything is working fine. Only issue is i'm unable to write test coverage for above showNTC getter.

Since the above code is executed only by visualforce expression, i'm unable to execute.
How do i write test coverage to execute above code ?

Thank you.

Test class so far i've written is something like this

```
 MyPage= Page.MyPage; //Page which attached to controller
 Test.setCurrentPage(MyPage); 
 StdConVR= new ApexPages.standardController(Obj);
System.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('id', obj.id);

Test.setCurrentPage(MyPage); 
StdConObj= new ApexPages.standardController(Obj);
ClassName testObj_Controller= new ClassName  ();
```

Comment: Can you post what you have so far of your test class?

Comment: Thank you...I've updated the question with testClass code, i've used sofar

Comment: use ' testObj_Controller.showNT = false' or system.assert( testObj_Controller.showNT);'

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried both the ways. 
testObj_Controller.showNT=false gave a compiled error while second option it gave a run time error (Assertion failed). Any possible reason?

Comment: Set the Status__c value and then use assert.

Comment: @TusharSharma it's private set, and even if it weren't the setter does not affect the getter results as written.

Comment: I used below code, But it gave an assertin failed error.
testObj_Controller.showNTC=true;
 system.assert( testObj_Controller.showNTC);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is good practice imo to use private setters as you have done. However, this means you can only directly call the getter (which usually calls the setter anyway). In your case, you actually don't even need a setter, because you are never actually setting your property value anywhere (`showNTC=...`).

Anyway, your test should be along the lines of:

```
static testMethod void testMyProperty_true()
{
    ClassName instance = new ClassName();
    // further manipulation so reg[0].Status__c == 'In Review')
    system.assertEquals(true, instance.showNTC, message);
}
static testMethod void testMyProperty_false()
{
    ClassName instance = new ClassName();
    // further manipulation so reg[0].Status__c != 'In Review')
    system.assertEquals(false, instance.showNTC, message);
}
```

Also, the property itself can be cleaned up to just:

```
public Boolean showNTC { get { return reg[0].Status__c == 'In Review'; } }
```

Some might prefer to make it an actual method when there is only a getter:

```
public Boolean getShowNTC() { return reg[0].Status__c == 'In Review'; }
```

which you would test slightly differently:

```
system.assertEquals(false, instance.getShowNTC());
```

---

To test a [lazy load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) on a query, your code might look like:

```
public List<Attachment> attachments
{
    get
    {
        if (attachments == null)
        {
            // attachments = [query];
        }
        return attachments;
    }
    private set;
}
```

Notice that here you are actually making use of the `setter`. Often I test hitting the `getter` multiple times to make sure I only query once:

```
static testMethod void testAttachments()
{
    // set up attachments
    Test.startTest();
        Integer startQueries = Limits.getQueries();
        List<Attachments> loadedAttachments;
        for (Integer i = 0; i < Limits.getLimitQueries(); i++)
            loadedAttachments = instance.attachments;
        Integer endQueries = Limits.getQueries();
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertEquals(1, endQueries, message);
    system.assertEquals(expectedSize, loadedAttachments.size(), message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it works fine.  It works fine for Boolean type. Is there any way if the getter returns non-boolean values
ex:
  public List<Attachment> attachments
    {
        get
        {
            if(attachments == null)
            {
              //something..
            }
            return attachments;
        }
        private set;
    }

Please tell me if there is any way? Thanks a lott..

Comment: @Chathura I added an example, but if you want more detail than what I provided, you might want to ask a separate question.

Comment: @Chathura Any more detail needed here? If this answer solved your issue, please accept it so as to help future members of the community.